# Cann't pouplate sqlite3 database table in my rails app using rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake

I have populated some data in my seeds.rb file that I used to seed a database table in my rails app. But today when I opened the rails app I did not see any data in my table. Subsequently I  tried to repopulate the database using rake db:seed but it just adds the id numbers but not the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your database and re-running the seeds:

```
rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:create && rake db:seed
```

Sometimes simply starting over is the easiest fix!

Comment: Hi Jeroen,thanks for the help. I dropped and recreated the database as per your suggestions but it did not fix the issue.